# Is it true that $\lvert\alpha+\beta\rvert=\lvert\alpha\rvert+\lvert\beta\rvert$ for ordinals $\alpha$ and $\beta$?

Tags: ordinals

Suppose $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are ordinals. I was asked to prove that $\lvert\alpha+\beta\rvert=\lvert\alpha\rvert+\lvert\beta\rvert$. However, I think to have found a counterexample for this equality, namely if $\alpha=\omega$ and $\beta=1$ then
$$\lvert\alpha+\beta\rvert=\lvert\omega+1\rvert=\lvert\omega\rvert=\omega\neq\omega+1=\lvert\alpha\rvert+\lvert\beta\rvert.$$
Am I doing something wrong or is there a mistake in the exercise?

Comment: You are confusing ordinal numbers and cardinal numbers. These are the dangers of using ordinals to denote both order types and cardinalities.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As I've mentioned in the comments, you are confusing ordinal and cardinal numbers. This is a very common mistake, and it's important to clarify it.

Let me add the subscript $c$ when we talk of cardinals and subscript $o$ when we talk of ordinals. Then we have $\alpha=\omega_o,\beta=1_o$. Then your argument is
$$|\alpha+\beta|=|\omega_o+1_o|=|\omega_o|=\omega_c\neq\omega_c+1_c=|\omega_o|+|1_o|=|\alpha|+|\beta|$$

Right now it's easy to see where the mistake is - in the world of cardinal numbers, equality $\omega_c=\omega_c+1_c$ *does* hold. This is why your counterexample is invalid.

**Edit**: As Noah points out, the alternative way to look at this is to note that the two ways in which you use $+$ are different - once it is an operation of *ordinal* sum, the other is *cardinal* sum.

As Asaf mentions, the safest way to go is to represent cardinals using aleph notation (which has become pretty much a standard in set theory), and leave $\omega$ to only denote ordinals.

Comment: I would emphasize this differently - put the subscript on the "$+$." Cardinal sums and ordinal sums are different (and this is a really important point once we start talking about exponentiation . . .).

Comment: I would just be smart about it and use the $\aleph$ notation. $|\omega|=\aleph_0$. Problem solved.

Comment: Thank you all for the hints! I now see what went wrong. A bit silly actually, but cardinals are relatively new to me.

Comment: In your 3rd sentence you are confusing ordinals and ordinals...